# Corollary of Hahn Banach theorem about norm

Tags: real-analysis

Let X a normed vectorial space on $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.Prove that $||x||=\sup_{T\in X^*,T\ne0}\frac{|Tx|}{||T||}=\sup_{||T||\le1,T\ne0}\frac{|Tx|}{||T||}= \sup_{||T||=1}{|Tx|}$.

My ideas is :

let $\gamma=\sup_{T\in X^*,T\ne0}\frac{|Tx|}{||T||}\quad\beta=\sup_{||T||\le1,T\ne0}\frac{|Tx|}{||T||},\quad\alpha=\sup_{||T||=1}{|Tx|}$ I know that $\gamma \ge \beta \ge \alpha$.
If I prove $\gamma\le \alpha$ then I prove the equality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality $\gamma\leq\alpha$ just follows from the fact that for every $T\ne 0$ we have that $S=\frac{T}{||T||}$ is a bounded functional which satisfies $||S||=1$. Then:

$\frac{|Tx|}{||T||}=|\frac{T}{||T||}x|=|Sx|\leq \sup_{||f||=1}|f(x)|=\alpha$

Since it is true for every $T\ne 0$ it is true for the supremum as well, i.e $\gamma\leq\alpha$.

So indeed $\alpha=\beta=\gamma$. However, that still doesn't prove that $||x||$ is equal to $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$. This is the interesting part. Suppose $x\ne 0$, otherwise the statement is trivial. Let $E=span\{x\}$ and define $f:E\to\mathbb{C}$ by $f(\lambda x)=\lambda ||x||$. This is clearly a linear functional on $E$. Also, for each $y=\lambda x\in E$ we have:

$|f(y)|=|f(\lambda x)|=|\lambda| ||x||=||\lambda x||=||y||$

So $f\in E^*$ and $||f||=1$. Also, $f(x)=||x||$. Now, by Hahn-Banach theorem we can extend $f$ to a functional $F\in X^*$ which satisfies $||F||=1$ and $F(x)=||x||$. This proves that:

$\alpha=\sup_{||T||=1}|Tx|\geq |F(x)|=||x||$

That's one inequality. On the other hand note that for each $T\in X^*, ||T||=1$ we have:

$|Tx|\leq ||T||\times ||x||=||x||$

Taking the supremum we get $\alpha=\sup_{||T||=1}|Tx|\leq ||x||$. This proves the other direction.

Comment: in the 3rd line of your proof who is f?

Comment: A general element in $X^*$ with norm $1$. I took the supremum on the set $\{f\in X^*: ||f||=1\}$.